# Angularjs promise and design issue in setting variables

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have done a design in which I have in a `uaContext` some useful information like the `productId` and the `operatorId`.
I need these information to display the content of each page.

```
myApp.service('uaContext', function($cookieStore){
    this.init = function() {
        this.isLogged = new Field();
        this.userName = new CookieField('userName', $cookieStore);

        this.appName = new Field();
        this.subAppName = new Field();

        this.operator = new Field();
        this.operatorList = new FilterField();

        this.product = new Field();
        this.productList = new FilterField();
    };

    this.init();
});
```

To be sure that I have the information, I catch the global `$routeChangeStart` event:

```
myApp.run( function($rootScope, $routeParams, uaViewProvider, uaAuthService, uaContext){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        if (uaContext.isLogged.get() == false && next.loginRequired != false){
            console.log('View requires to be logged in');
            if (uaAuthService.sessionCookieExists() == true){
                console.log('Recover session from Cookie');

                uaAuthService.loadSession().then(function() {
                    uaContext.operator.set(uaContext.operatorList.filter('id', +$routeParams.operatorId));
                    uaContext.productList.set(uaContext.operator.get().products);
                    uaContext.product.set(uaContext.productList.filter('id', +$routeParams.productId));
                });
            } else{
                console.log('User not logged in. Redirect to login.');
                uaViewProvider.redirectToView('login');
            }
        }

    });
});
```

In this case when I recover a session thanks to a cookie, I requested to reload the session with the `loadSession` promise. Then I define the `productId` and `operatorId` based on the url parameters.

The issue is that in a view I need to get these parameters before requesting more information:

```
var myApp2 = angular.module('ua.myApp2', []);

myApp2.controller('ua.myApp2Controller',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, uaContext, uaApiInterface) {
        $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
            uaContext.appName.set('Settings');
            uaContext.subAppName.set('Sims');

        });

        console.log('On route change');

        $scope.$watch(function(){
            watchValue = uaContext.operator.get().id + '-' + uaContext.product.get().id
            return watchValue;
        }, function(){
            uaApiInterface.getSimList(uaContext.operator.get().id,uaContext.product.get().id).then(
                function(objects) {
                    console.log('Then');
                    $scope.simList = objects.data.objects;
                    console.log($scope.simList);
                    console.log(objects.data.objects);

                }
            )
        },true);
    }
);
```

The only solution I found to wait the end of the `loadSession` promise is to put a watch on the `operatorId` and `productId`.

The issue is that I will have to define this watch for **all my views**. This is really not dry so my question is how can I optimize this?

Comment: As I know we have several options: create directive and implement `$watch` there. To use only one controller for all views (aka use view like fragment)

Comment: Thank you. Isn't it possible to wait the end of the promise to finish the routing? A synchronous call will be the solution but it not seems to be available in Angularjs...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to put this code:

```
uaAuthService.loadSession().then(function() {
    uaContext.operator.set(uaContext.operatorList.filter('id', +$routeParams.operatorId));
    uaContext.productList.set(uaContext.operator.get().products);
    uaContext.product.set(uaContext.productList.filter('id', +$routeParams.productId));
})
```

In the context service.

Then in each view, the entry point is:

```
uaContext.getSession().then(...
```

If you have any comment or suggestion.